# Limit/Filter Foreign Key Choices in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Consider an app where people can participate in a contest.

I have a `Contest` and `ContestProblem` Model ready. I want to have following features for the contest:

1. A contest can have many problems
2. **A problem can not appear in more than one contest**

In my `models.py`, I have:

```
class ProblemsInContest(CreateUpdateDateModel):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest)
    problem = models.ForeignKey(ContestProblem)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Problem in Contest"
        verbose_name_plural = "Problems in Contest"

    def __str__(self):
        return "{problem}".format(problem=self.problem)
```

In my admin.py, I have:

```
class ContestProblemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProblemsInContest
    extra = 1


class ContestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [
        ContestProblemInline,
    ]
```

This is how my Admin Form look:
[image]

I am using Django Admin to add problems to a contest. The problem being the fact that in the Problem dropdown, it shows me all the `ContestProblem` but I want to limit it to only those `ContestProblem` which does not appear in any other contest.

Any hints or advice or references to achieve the desired results will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can look into (unique=True) for problems inside ProblemsInContest

Comment: @Vaibhav I tried the same, but that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class ContestProblemInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = ProblemsInContest

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):

        field = super(RoomInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

        if db_field.name == 'your_field_name':
            if request._obj_ is not None:
                field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(your_field_name = request._obj_)  
            else:
                field.queryset = field.queryset.none()

        return field



class ContestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = (ContestProblemInline,)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # just save obj reference for future processing in Inline
        request._obj_ = obj
        return super(ContestAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: can you please let me know the part of the code that filter problems that have appeared before in any contest?

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of the line `field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(your_field_name = request._obj_)`